# How to validate against Multiple validation groups?

Tags: asp.net, validation, validationgroup

I have two validation groups:  parent and child

I have an add button that needs to only validate the child validation group which is easily done.  The save button needs to validate against the parent and child validation groups, both client side and server side.  I think I know how to do it server side by calling the Page.Validate("groupname") method for each group, but how can it be done client side?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this by creating a javascript function that uses [Page_ClientValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338815%28v=VS.71%29.aspx) and then having the button call that function

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" Text="Save" OnClientClick="return validate()" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var t1 = Page_ClientValidate("parent");
        var t2 = Page_ClientValidate("child");

        if (!t1 || !t2) return false;

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I think you need to change OnClientClick to "return validate()"

Answer (score 4):

The problem with CAbbott's answer is that validation errors that occur in the "parent" group will not be displayed after the call to validate the "child" group.  The more minor problem with Oleg's answer is that validation of the "child" group will not occur until the "parent" group is ready.

All we really need to do to allow client-side validation of more than one group at the same time is to override the Javascript IsValidationGroupMatch method which determines whether or not a control is to be included in the current set being validated.

For example:

```
(function replaceValidationGroupMatch() {

    // If this is true, IsValidationGroupMatch doesn't exist - oddness is afoot!
    if (!IsValidationGroupMatch) throw "WHAT? IsValidationGroupmatch not found!";

    // Replace ASP.net's IsValidationGroupMatch method with our own...
    IsValidationGroupMatch = function(control, validationGroup) {
        if (!validationGroup) return true;

        var controlGroup = '';
        if (typeof(control.validationGroup) === 'string') controlGroup = control.validationGroup;

        // Deal with potential multiple space-delimited groups being validated
        var validatingGroups = validationGroup.split(' ');

        for (var i = 0; i < validatingGroups.length; i++) {
            if (validatingGroups[i] === controlGroup) return true;
        }

        // Control's group not in any being validated, return false
        return false;
    };
} ());

// You can now validate against multiple groups at once, for example:
// space-delimited list.  This would validate against the Decline group:
//
//  Page_ClientValidate('Decline');
//
// while this would validate against the Decline, Open and Complete groups:
//
//  Page_ClientValidate('Open Decline Complete');
//
// so if you wanted to validate all three upon click of a button, you'd do:

<asp:Button ID="yourButton" runat="server" 
    OnClick="ButtonSave_Click" CausesValidation="false" 
    OnClientClick="return Page_ClientValidate('Open Decline Complete');" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call Page_ClientValidate(..) twice, only the last validation result will be shown and it can be OK while the first is not. So the second call should be made only if the first has returned true

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var parentOk= Page_ClientValidate('parent');
    var childOk = false;
    if (parentOk) {
        childOk = Page_ClientValidate('child');
    }

    return parentOk && childOk;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever way you do it requires some hacking to get round ASP.Net's assumption that you wouldn't try to do this. I favour a reusable approach which is explicit about the hackery involved.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebSandbox.Validators
{
    /// <summary>
    ///   <para>
    ///     Validates a different validation group. Among the use cases envisioned are
    ///     <list type="">
    ///       <item>
    ///         Validating one set of rules when the user clicks "Save draft" and validating those rules plus some
    ///         extra consistency checks when they click "Send".
    ///       </item>
    ///       <item>
    ///         Grouping controls in a <code>fieldset</code> into a validation group with a
    ///         <code>ValidationSummary</code> and then having a final <code>ValidationSummary</code> which tells the
    ///         user which groups still have errors.
    ///       </item>
    ///     </list>
    ///   </para>
    ///   <para>
    ///     We include checks against setting <code>GroupToValidate</code> to the same value as
    ///     <code>ValidationGroup</code>, but we don't yet include checks for infinite recursion with one validator
    ///     in group A which validates group B and another in group B which validates group A. Caveat utilitor.
    ///   </para>
    /// </summary>
    public class ValidationGroupValidator : BaseValidator
    {
        public string GroupToValidate
        {
            get { return ViewState["G2V"] as string; }
            set { ViewState["G2V"] = value; }
        }

        protected override bool ControlPropertiesValid()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupToValidate)) throw new HttpException("GroupToValidate not specified");
            if (GroupToValidate == ValidationGroup) throw new HttpException("Circular dependency");
            // Don't call the base, because we don't want a "control to validate"
            return true;
        }

        protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);

            writer.AddAttribute("evaluationfunction", "ValidateValidationGroup");
            writer.AddAttribute("GroupToValidate", GroupToValidate);
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            // The standard validation JavaScript is too restrictive for this validator to work, so we have to replace a key function.
            // Fortunately this runs later than the standard JS, so we can simply overwrite the existing value of Page_ClientValidate.
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(ValidationGroupValidator), "validationJS", _ValidationJS);

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }

        protected override bool EvaluateIsValid()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(GroupToValidate)) return false;

            bool groupValid = true;
            foreach (IValidator validator in Page.GetValidators(GroupToValidate))
            {
                validator.Validate();
                groupValid &= validator.IsValid;
            }

            return groupValid;
        }

        private const string _ValidationJS = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
function ValidateValidationGroup(val) {
    if (typeof(val.GroupToValidate) == ""string"") {
        val.valid = PageMod_DoValidation(val.GroupToValidate);
    }
}

function Page_ClientValidate(validationGroup) {
    Page_InvalidControlToBeFocused = null;
    if (!Page_Validators) return true;

    var i, ctrl;

    // Mark everything as valid.
    for (i = 0; i &lt; Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        Page_Validators[i].finalValid = true;
    }
    if (Page_ValidationSummaries) {
        for (i = 0; i &lt; Page_ValidationSummaries.length; i++) {
            Page_ValidationSummaries[i].finalDisplay = ""none"";
        }
    }

    // Validate.
    var groupValid = PageMod_DoValidation(validationGroup);

    // Update displays once.
    for (i = 0; i &lt; Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        ctrl = Page_Validators[i];
        ctrl.isvalid = ctrl.finalValid;
        ValidatorUpdateDisplay(ctrl);
    }
    if (Page_ValidationSummaries) {
        for (i = 0; i &lt; Page_ValidationSummaries.length; i++) {
            ctrl = Page_ValidationSummaries[i];
            ctrl.style.display = ctrl.finalDisplay;
        }
    }

    ValidatorUpdateIsValid();
    Page_BlockSubmit = !Page_IsValid;
    return Page_IsValid;
}

function PageMod_DoValidation(validationGroup) {
    var groupValid = true, validator, i;
    for (i = 0; i &lt; Page_Validators.length; i++) {
        validator = Page_Validators[i];
        ValidatorValidate(validator, validationGroup, null);
        validator.finalValid &amp;= validator.isvalid;
        groupValid &amp;= validator.isvalid;
    }

    if (Page_ValidationSummaries) {
        ValidationSummaryOnSubmit(validationGroup, groupValid);

        var summary;
        for (i = 0; i &lt; Page_ValidationSummaries.length; i++) {
            summary = Page_ValidationSummaries[i];
            if (summary.style.display !== ""none"") summary.finalDisplay = summary.style.display;
        }
    }

    return groupValid;
}
</script>";
    }
}
```