# Is it possible to assign Multiple Validation Groups to a single Validation Control?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net, validation

I have a Form like this.

UserID has to be validated when user clicks "Check Availability" and "Submit"[image]

Hence "UserID" required field validator has to be assigned two grops.

As if now it is assigned only Group1

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserIDRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter UserID"
                    ControlToValidate="txtUserID" ValidationGroup="Group1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

So is it possible to assign "Group1" and "Group2" to UserIDRequiredFieldValidator

I have already gone through
[How to validate against Multiple validation groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509369/how-to-validate-against-multiple-validation-groups) 
which talks about validating Group1 and Group2 when user clicks "Submit" which is a good alternate solution .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please check this an older but effective [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509369/how-to-validate-against-multiple-validation-groups)

Comment: I think the linked Post is a better solution than duplicating validation markup

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What about using two RequiredFieldValidator objects, one for Group1 and one for Group2?

Comment: Good Solution.. Definitely solves the issue..But is it not possible to  assign multiple groups to a validation control ?

Comment: No it is not possible but you can call Page.Validate("groupOne");
Page.Validate("groupTwo"); from code behind.

Comment: I thought multiple validation groups was primarily to solve the problem of using multiple required field validators. They like to all fire (on blur) instead of accepting one false result is enough.