# How can I achieve the effect of multiple validation groups on a single validation control?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, validationgroup

I need to be able to apply multiple validation groups to some of the controls on my page, because for each of the three submit "modes", there is a different set of required fields.

I have three submit buttons, and each one has its own validation group (reject, approve, and save). "Reject" doesn't actually have any required fields currently, but may in the future. "Save" only requires "first name" and "last name", while "approve" requires "first name", "last name", as well as "group name".

I tried simply putting multiple validation groups in the attribute value (as in the code below), but the validation didn't fire at all.

I also tried not specifying a group at all in an attempt to just have the validation always fire, but again again, it didn't fire at all.

```
<div>
    <label for='<%= txt_FirstName.ClientID %>'>First Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_FirstName" runat="server" text="Required"
        ControlToValidate="txt_FirstName" ValidationGroup="approve save">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<div>
    <label for='<%= txt_LastName.ClientID %>'>Last Name</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_LastName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_LastName" runat="server" text="Required"
        ControlToValidate="txt_LastName" ValidationGroup="approve save">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<div>
    <label for='<%= ddl_GroupName.ClientID %>'>Group Name</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_GroupName" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv_GroupName" runat="server" text="Required"
        ControlToValidate="ddl_GroupName" ValidationGroup="approve">
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btn_Reject" runat="server" Text="Reject"
        ValidationGroup="reject" OnClick="btn_Reject_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn_Approve" runat="server" Text="Approve"
        ValidationGroup="approve" OnClick="btn_Approve_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="btn_Save" runat="server" Text="Save"
        ValidationGroup="save" OnClick="btn_Save_Click" />
</div>
```

I'm certain I can achieve the desired effect with some additional code, or duplicated validator controls for each validation group, but I was hoping the webforms framework would have a simpler, built-in way to do this.

UPDATE (2018-01-02):
The question ["Is it possible to assign Multiple Validation Groups to a single Validation Control?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295838) is a special case of my own. It has a single control in multiple groups, whereas I have multiple controls with multiple overlapping groups. Additionally, the answer proposes having a validation control for each input/group combination. This is a terrible solution because, among other things, it violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) programming principle and makes maintenance/enhancements more difficult.

The above also links the question ["How to validate against Multiple validation groups?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509369). That question is a completely different issue (validation groups within validation groups), and its answer proposes custom javascript that would need to be written for every submit button, on every page that requires multiple validation groups.

I am looking for a general case solution that I can write/implement once and apply to the entirety of the web application, and thus I do not consider my question a duplicate of the above mentioned questions.

UPDATE (2018-01-03):
Between other questions/articles I've encountered while researching my problem, as well as the gracious assistance of a.bajorinas and Sunil, I've established that it is not possible to have multiple validation groups on a validation control out-of-the-box, and custom code will be required to achieve the desired effect. I've updated the question accordingly, to assist anyone looking to achieve this in the future.

I'll be testing a solution that incorporates elements from both a.bajorinas' and Sunil's answers and will hopefully be able to provide an update afterward.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to assign Multiple Validation Groups to a single Validation Control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295838/is-it-possible-to-assign-multiple-validation-groups-to-a-single-validation-contr)

Comment: You can try the answer that I have posted, which has been tested by me. Note that the button that validates multiple groups should have a comma delimited list specified for validationGroup property  as in `ValidationGroup="group1, group2"`. Also, multiple validation groups should be specified at the submit control level like for a button, but not for a validator that does not submit the page.

Comment: @a.bajorinas Please see the edit for my explanation as to why this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of for your desired use case, is setting `ValidationGroup` for your validators in code behind on button click, keep in mind that this would first perform a postback and then validate the controls which might not be ok for you.

```
protected void btn_save_click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    rfv_FirstName.ValidationGroup = "save";
    Page.Validate("save");
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        //logic if validators pass
    }
}
```

This will let you reuse validators for multiple groups.
Also in my linked posted, one of the comments to the selected answer is "It is not possible to assign multiple groups to a validation control"

Comment: We do need to have client side validation as well as server, but I think we'll be able to cobble together a reusable solution based on both your and Sunil's suggestions. I probably won't have time to test this for another week or two, but I appreciate the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.Net does not support multiple validation groups. However, with a little bit of JavaScript code you can make it support multiple validation groups.
What you need to do is override the standard JavaScript function of `IsValidationGroupMatch`. This function is part of the standard validation library in ASP.Net.

At bottom of your aspx page, just add the script tag given below. Note that this script is just before closing form, body and html tags, which is important when overriding a JavaScript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            window["IsValidationGroupMatch"] = function (control, validationGroup) {
                if ((typeof (validationGroup) == "undefined") || (validationGroup == null)) {
                    return true;
                }
                var controlGroup = "";
                var isGroupContained = false;
                if (typeof (control.validationGroup) == "string") {
                    controlGroup = control.validationGroup;
                    var controlGroupArray = [];
                    if (validationGroup.indexOf(",") > -1) {
                        controlGroupArray = validationGroup.split(",");// validationGroup.split(",");
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < controlGroupArray.length; i++) {
                        if (controlGroupArray[i].trim() == controlGroup.trim()) {
                            isGroupContained = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return (controlGroup == validationGroup || isGroupContained);
            }
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Once you do this, then you can add a comma delimited list of validation groups for the button that validates multiple validation groups as in example below. In example below a button with id of `btnMultipleValidationGroups` is validating group1 as well as group2.

```
<div>
            TextBox1 : 
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="TextBox1 needs input"  ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="group1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <br />
            <br />
            TextBox2 : 
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="TextBox2 needs input"  ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="group2"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <br />
            TextBox3 :
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="TextBox3 needs input"  ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="group3"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            <br />
            <br />
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnMultipleValidationGroups" runat="server" Text="Validate group1 and group2" ValidationGroup="group1,group2" OnClick="btnMultipleValidationGroups_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnGroup1" runat="server" Text="Validate only group1" ValidationGroup="group1" OnClick="btnGroup1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnGroup2" runat="server" Text="Validate only group2" ValidationGroup="group2" OnClick="btnGroup2_Click" />
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I was hoping to avoid needing to write any custom code to achieve this functionality, but it looks like I could apply your solution to the whole web site, which could be useful going forward with this project.

Comment: Yes, you could apply it to whole project by adding that script to the master page. Like I said, ASP.Net does not support multiple groups. Also, keep in mind that you must use multiple groups only on submit controls like button and not on validators.

Comment: Ah, I missed that last bit when I was first reviewing this solution. We need the validators themselves to have the multiple groups, not the buttons. Leave it to Microsoft to make a seemingly simple task so darn complicated. ;)

Comment: @Eric, Having multiple validation groups for a validator makes no sense, since  a validator other than custom validator can be tied to one and only one control. So, you cannot have a RequiredFieldValidator that validates two text boxes i.e. it must validate only one text box. Due to this fact, it makes no sense to have multiple validation groups for a single validator.

Comment: I'm not needing one validator to validate multiple controls. I need one validator to validate one control when one of multiple available validation groups are active. For example, require TextBox1 when the validation group "group1" or "group2" is active, but not when "group3" is active.

Comment: Then, you should try adding multiple validation groups as I have mentioned in my answer to the validation control.  Add appropriate groups to button that causes validation.